# SMTP Server Dovecot / Exim Authentication error

Tags: centos, dovecot, exim

Recently, I've installed the centOS 6. The purpose of the installation to use this server as Mail server. Where I've installed **Exim version 4.84_2 #1** and **Dovecot**.

I've followed this blog [post](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/setup-a-mailserver-with-exim-and-dovecot-on-a-centos-7-vps/) and I've tried to solve the below given error, however I do not have luck to resolve it.

```
  2017-02-06 07:07:27 no host name found for IP address x.x.x.x
    2017-02-06 07:07:32 dovecot_plain authenticator failed for ([x.x.x.x]) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mailclown@com-supportnet.work)
    2017-02-06 07:07:40 dovecot_plain authenticator failed for ([x.x.x.x]) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mailclown@com-supportnet.work)
    2017-02-06 07:07:48 dovecot_login authenticator failed for ([x.x.x.x]) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mailclown@com-supportnet.work)
    2017-02-06 07:07:52 dovecot_login authenticator failed for ([x.x.x.x]) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mailclown@com-supportnet.work)
```

Following is the output the configuration which I used from the above blog post.

```
[root@com-supportnet ~]# dovecot -n
# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS release 6.8 (Final) 
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb
mail_location = maildir:~/mail
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
service auth {
  unix_listener auth-client {
    mode = 0777
    user = exim
  }
}
ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/mail.com-supportnet.work.crt
ssl_key = /etc/ssl/mail.com-supportnet.work.key
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Please let me know, how I can resolve this error.

Comment: Did you use pop3s or imaps on Dovecot? Why did you enable plain text login when you used secure pop3 and imap?

Comment: Dovecot configuration : disabled_plaintext_auth= yes and ssl= required

Comment: Okay let me try it.

Comment: Starting Dovecot Imap: doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf line 39: Unknown setting: disabled_plaintext_auth
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: Solved above errors, but I'm getting same error     2017-02-06 07:07:48 dovecot_login authenticator failed for ([x.x.x.x]) [x.x.x.x]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=mailclown@com-supportnet.work)

Comment: Which authentication method did you use? You used Linux User or others to login to mailserver? By default, I used linux user to login to mailserver.

Comment: I'm using the Linux user to login

Comment: Are you sure you're 'user' is 'exim'? In Debian for example the system user is 'Debian-exim' thought it appears you're using CentOS and perhaps they use 'exim'.

Comment: @supriady 'plain' login can be used in conjunction with TLS. https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/Mechanisms

Comment: I too bumped into this issue. no answer yet

Answer (score 0):

If anyone just bumps here as I did, I solved this in Gentoo via:

```bsh
# cd /etc/pam.d/ && ln -s imap smtp
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).